# Search on table with recursive structure

Tags: mysql, yii2

I have to generate 2 reports: "Expenses by Category" and "Expenses by subcategory". Since the structure of my bank is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `category` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `parent_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `desc_category` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
 `created` datetime NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `id` (`id`)
) 

/----------------------------------------------------\
| id | parent_id | desc_category   |user_id| created |
|----|-----------|-----------------|-------|---------|
| 1  | NULL      | Residence       | 9     | ...     |
| 2  | 1         | Rent            | 9     | ...     |
| 3  | 1         | maintenance     | 9     | ...     |
| 4  | NULL      | Person          | 9     | ...     |
| 5  | 4         | Alimentation    | 9     | ...     |
| 6  | 4         | school          | 9     | ...     |
\----------------------------------------------------/
```

The report "Expenses by Subcategory" worked doing so:

```
SELECT desc_category AS cat, value FROM cashbook
            INNER JOIN category
            ON cashbook.category_id = category.id_category
            WHERE category.user_id = $user AND type_id = 2 AND MONTH(date) = $thismonth AND YEAR(date) = $thisyear
```

How do I Expenses by Category? (For example **Residence** and **Person**)

Picking up `where parent_id is NULL`?

Comment: That worked without grouping or ordering?

Comment: @Uueerdo **Expenses by Subcategory** work fine as sql example. **Expenses by Category** I do not know how to do